# Conditional mapping for two plugins (UltiSnips and Vimwiki)

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimwiki

Vimwiki table default mappings include `<tab>` for moving to the next table column in insert mode.
Also UltiSnips default mappings include `<tab>` for expanding snippets in insert mode.
Here is the result for `:verbose imap <tab>`

```
i  <Tab>       *@vimwiki#tbl#kbd_tab()
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimwiki/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim line 543
i  <Tab>       * <C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim line 61
```

When I intend to use a snippet inside a vimwiki table, `<tab>` doesn't work - it just follows the vimwiki mapping and takes cursor to the next column. I would like to have `<tab>` work for both, i.e., if Ultisnips is not triggering results then use Vimwiki, otherwise use UltiSnips. I had mentioned this issue at vimwiki repo on github and [was suggested to use a conditional](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/1021#issuecomment-715925455).

I don't really know how to add conditionals for two different plugin mappings, hence asking for help. How do I achieve this?

---

P.S. There are a few "solutions" to this problem, for instance, as suggested [here](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/357#issuecomment-308935540), one can add

```
let g:vimwiki_table_mappins = 0
```

to their `.vimrc` and then use a different mapping for `vimwiki#tbl#kbd_tab()`. There are other solutions in that thread as well.

But the reason I am wanting to have conditionals is that it let's me keep same old mappings and also according to [vimwiki helpfile](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/619f04f89861c58e5a6415a4f83847752928252d/doc/vimwiki.txt#L3617), `g:vimwiki_table_mappings` option will be fully removed at a later point. Then the above wouldn't work. It also seems like a general problem to me to have the same keybinding for different plugin mappings using conditionals.

---

I would thankful for any help on this, even for a sketch of how to do it.